# Cluodflare, https, права администратора

Tags: wordpress, https

Добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, подключил сайт к Cloudflare, там есть SSL. После того как сайт стал доступен через https зашел в админку и поменял в настройках URL. После этого сайт остается доступным, но не могу войти в админку (браузер выдает ошибку, что слишком много редиректов).

В интернете нашел, что в таком случае нужно в `wp-config.php` добавить

> $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

После этого, когда ввожу логин и пароль получаю сообщение: **Извините, вам не разрешено просматривать эту страницу** (Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page).
Пробовал через базу данных менять поле `wp_capabilities` на `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` в таблице `user_meta`. Ничего.

Пробовал также создать нового юзера с правами администратора (с ним в итоге получается та же история, тоже вход невозможен), деактивировать все плагины, менять настройки в .htaccess (сейчас оставил дефолтные ВП)... ничего не получилось.

Как только меняю в БД site_url на без https, всё работает.

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: И снова о том же. Отвечали уже здесь много раз. Вам надо сайт полностью перевести  на https. Прочитайте вот этот ответ о том, как правильно переносить сайт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: Так дело в том, что сайт (фронт) работает нормально и все отображается (везде где нужно https), только не могу как администратор войти.

Comment: Вот ровно потому и не можете. А то, что фронт отображается - просто повезло. На более сложных сайтах и он отображаться не будет. В моём ответе по ссылке всё расписано.

Comment: Если вы о сериализованных массивах, то все нужные урлы в БД заменены на https с помощью плагина Better Search Replace

Comment: Вся проблема была в том, что эту строку '$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';' нужно было добавить в начало файла, а не в конец

Comment: Все эти советы - неправильные. У меня много сайтов на https + cloudflare, ни на одном такой ерундой не занимался.

Comment: Т.е. в моем случае было бы правильно воспользоваться плагином Database Search and Replace или WP Migrate DB?

Comment: Я бы советовал Duplicator, как самое простое решение.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, спасибо за ваши ответы. Один момент для меня до конца не ясен. Перед переходом на https нужно сделать дамп базы+инсталлер и потом заново сделать установку ВП?

Comment: Нет, не надо новой установки. Заливаете дамп базы (.zip) + инсталлер  на сайт, и запускаете инсталлер.